# Parse XSLT attribute as an array

Tags: html, xml, forms, parsing, xslt

I'm using XSLT to create HTML forms from XML. Forms are dynamically created. There is no ready teamplate for that. There will be as many inputs as user wants. I want to keep it as short as possible so I'm using attributes to create e.g. options in select tags. The problem is that I can't figure out how to turn this XML:

```
<input mapTo="dropdown" nameId="sampleId" inputDomain="[a, b, c, d, e]" />
```

into:

```
<select id="sampleId">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
```

My problem is exactly the `inputDomain` attribute. I can modify for an easier method but I want to keep it in one attribute (like an array). Is it possible? Or maybe you have more convenient ideas?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you want to use, which XSLT version? If XML is used as the data format and XSLT is used as the processing language then what kind of XML structure or XSLT known data type is `SET:[a, b, c, d, e]` supposed to represent?

Comment: As I said I can modify it to e.g. `[a, b, c, d, e]`. I just want to know if there is any way to provide multiple options in one attribute. I'm also not strictly bound to versions of anything. I'm flexible with this.

Comment: Do you find that representation in https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-attribute-types? Or in https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-derived? And which XSLT processor, which XSLT version can you use?

Comment: Hmm. I think there is no representation like I wrote. As I said, I can use any version of XSLT, just to make it work. For now, my XSL file uses `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`. So there isn't completely any way to get some strings divided by comma or whatever in XML attribute?

Comment: There a list data types like NMTOKENS but you partly depend on DTD or schema support. And of course XSLT 2 with XPath 2 functions has functions like `tokenize`. With an XSLT 1 processor there might be support for an extension function doing the job. But it will short fall if your data gets more complex and the token separator can appear in your data values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input mapTo="dropdown" nameId="sampleId" inputDomain="a,b,c,d,e" />
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <select id="sampleId">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@inputDomain, ',')">
            <option value="{.}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </select>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<select id="sampleId">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
   <option value="c">c</option>
   <option value="d">d</option>
   <option value="e">e</option>
</select>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiL

Answer (score 1):

If you use schema-aware XSLT 2 or 3 (e.g. with Saxon 9 or 10 EE) you can declare the attribute as type `xs:NMTOKENS` and use a space separated list:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="input">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="inputDomain" type="xs:NMTOKENS" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="mapTo" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:attribute name="nameId" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then a stylesheet processing

```
<input mapTo="dropdown" nameId="sampleId" inputDomain="a b c d e" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
```

can use the `data` function on the attribute to have a sequence of tokens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="input[@mapTo = 'dropdown']">
        <select id="{@nameId}">
            <xsl:for-each select="data(@inputDomain)">
                <option value="{.}">{.}</option>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Example</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```